# Parameterising order column name and sort order for MySQL queries in Ballerina

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, ballerina

I need to parameterise the ordering column name and sort order (ASC/DESC) in a `sql:ParameterizedQuery`.

i.e:

```
`SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> ORDER BY ${<COLUMN_NAME>} ${<SORT_ORDER>}`
```

Here is the code I tried to use, but this doesn't seems to be working.

```text
sqlQuery = sql:queryConcat( sqlQuery, ` ORDER BY ${'order.columnName} ${'order.sortOrder}`)
```

I guess only the values are supported as params in `sql:ParameterizedQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, only values are supported as params. For this use case, multiple `sql:ParameterizedQuery` needs to be defined.

The specific query can be selected using a match case.